# Hide or display none for backgroundImage using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, background-image

`$('.arrow').backgroundImage="url('../img/arrow.png').style.display = 'none'";`

I am using an animate.css plugin to hide the down arrow on scroll down.

```
`$( document ).ready(function() {     
console.log( "ready!" ); 
    $("h1").animate({color:"#ffffff"}, 600);
    $('.arrow').backgroundImage="url('../img/arrow.png')";`

if (direction == "up") {
    $("h1").animate({color:"#ffffff"}, 600);
    $('.arrow').backgroundImage="url('../img/arrow.png')";
```

`} else if (direction == "down") { 
        $("h1").animate({color:"#444444"}, 600);
        $('.arrow').backgroundImage="url('../img/arrow.png').style.display = 'none'";`

The arrow isn't working. Is my function written incorrectly? How do I hide backgroundImage? 
Is there a better/efficient way to work around this?

Comment: You can't chain to the object from the property assignment. Just make it hidden then set the background image.

Comment: No wait. You're trying to set the background image itself to display none. It doesn't work that way. Just remove the image and add back as needed

Comment: Code suggestion: Start using animations/transitions with CSS3 to at least keep the #FFF value inside some css class. Otherwise you will have problems with refactoring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean way to do the show and hide would be to use CSS classes to override the `background-image` property.

Assuming the following CSS class selector is already defined:

```
.arrow {
    background-image: url("../img/arrow.png");
}
```

Add another CSS class selector definition:

```
.arrow.hide-bg {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Update your JS code portion to add or remove the CSS class accordingly:

```
if (direction == "up") {
    $("h1").animate({color:"#ffffff"}, 600);
    $('.arrow').removeClass("hide-bg");
} else if (direction == "down") {
    $("h1").animate({color:"#444444"}, 600);
    $('.arrow').addClass("hide-bg");
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much Tanzeel!
This method worked the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the image using the hide() function

```
$('.arrow').hide();
```

To set the background you can make use of the .css function of jquery like:

```
$('.arrow').css("background","url('../img/arrow.png')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it works for you.

```
if (direction == "up") { 
   $('.arrow').css('background-image','../img/arrow.png'); } 
else if (direction == "down") { 
   $('.arrow').css('background-image','none'); 
}
```

Comment: However, the arrow doesn't appear back when I scroll up :/

Answer (score 0):

I give you another posible solution.

```
$('.arrow').css('display', 'none');
```

But it's more common to do:

```
$('.arrow').hide();
```

Comment: However, the arrow doesn't appear back when I scroll up :/