# Delaying backgroung image in web2py view

Tags: python, web2py

I would like to give the `background-image` it's own class so I can use the javascript code on it. However, if I remove it from the current div the `background-image` can not be displayed because it is the `background-image` for this `div`.

This is the web2py `View`:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

{{for color in bg:}}
<div class="project_video" style="background-image: url('{{=URL('download', args=color.bg_picture)}}')">
{{pass}}

<video class="movie" style="width: 100%;" src="{{=URL('download', args=videos.clip)}}" autoplay poster="{{=URL('static', 'images/tabla_loading_poster.png')}}" onended=videoEnded()></video>

<div class="objects" hidden>
{{for pic in pics_objects:}}
<a href="{{=URL('pic_answer', args=pic.id)}}"><img src="{{=URL('download', args=pic.pictures)}}"/></a>
<audio autoplay src="{{=URL('static', 'images/pop.mp3')}}"></audio>
{{pass}}
</div>
    </div>
```

Of course if I use the javascript on the `project_video` class it will apply to the entire `div`. not only to the `background-image`.

This is the web2py `Controller` for the above `View`:

```
def game():
    videos = db.vid(request.args(0,cast=int)) or redirect(URL('index'))
    bg = db(db.back.owner_id==request.args(0)).select()
    pics_objects = db(db.pic.owner_id==request.args(0,cast=int)).select()
    return locals()
```

This is the javascript bellow but, as I mentioned, this will hide the whole `div` and what I want to hide is the `background-image` only:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.project_video').hide();
});
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.project_video').delay(6000).show(0);
});
</script>
```

I would appreciate any advise.

Comment: You cannot set a CSS class on a background image. What exactly do you need to do with that image via JavaScript?

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for your comment Anthony, I edited my post and added the javascript. I want to hide the `background image` at first and I only want to show it after the video is fully loaded and playing.

Comment: @Anthony Hello Anthony, is what I am trying to do here possible? Do you have any suggestions? Please kindly let me know. Thanks very much!

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439145/hide-or-display-none-for-backgroundimage-using-jquery